# How do I populate the contents from EditText in ListView?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview

I have a layout file in which I have defined a `ListView` and another layout file in which I have defined the style of the individual list element. `OnClick` how do I populate my `ListView` by using the other layout? Or is it even possible to do so?

This is my ListView

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chat_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
    >
</ListView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/form"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</RelativeLayout>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/chat"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_button"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icons_chat"
    android:height="20dp"
    android:width="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:onClick="sendChat"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/chat"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
```

This is my other layout

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/user_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/chat_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

`OnClick` I want to `getText` from the `EditText` in the first layout and update the `ListView` using the style in the second layout. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to said when you wrote `...using the style in the second layout...` I'm really I don't understand what do you needed... store dynamically a element `onClick` event?

Comment: please add more details........your Activity class and custom adapter class

Comment: @Aspicas My question is.. Is there any way that I can use the second layout as individual chats messages and render it in my listview. If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think that one way to do it is  with an `ArrayAdapter` which will adapt your `Collection` (which you want to use) to your items in your layout `ListView` for your case. For example

```
 public class YourActivity extends Activity {

        private ListView listView;

        public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
             setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

             listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.you_list_id);

             //Here you can set values from your edit texts
             ArrayList<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
             yourArrayList.add("someTextFromYourEditTexts");
             yourArrayList.add("someTextFromYourEditTexts");

           //Create your ArrayAdapter with your already populate array list
             ArrayAdapter<String> yourArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                     this, 
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                     yourArrayList );

             //And when your adapter is create set it to your list view
             listView.setAdapter(yourArrayAdapter); 
        }
    }
```